# append a list of named tuple with another tuple

Tags: python, namedtuple

I have created a namedtuple using below

```
supply_nodes_list=list(df_supply_nodes.itertuples(name='supplynode', index=False))
```

Output of the above code is as follows.

```
[supplynode(Supply_nodes=1, capacities=15), supplynode(Supply_nodes=2, capacities=20)]
```

I need to add another tuple to this list and output need to be as below.

```
[supplynode(Supply_nodes=1, capacities=15), supplynode(Supply_nodes=2, capacities=20),supplynode(Supply_nodes=dummy, capacities=1000000)]
```

Tried on as below

```
supply_nodes_list.append('supplynode'(Supply_nodes='dummy', capacities='100000'))
```

this giving me an error

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: Have you tried to `.append()`?

Comment: @DYZ just tried below... supply_nodes_list.append('supplynode'(Supply_nodes='dummy', capacities=100000));but giving an error as 'TypeError: 'str' object is not callable'

Comment: ` supply_nodes_list.append(supplynode(Supply_nodes='dummy', capacities=100000))`

Comment: @drum = ,supply_nodes_list.append(supplynode(Supply_nodes='dummy', capacities=100000))`,this is not working.E

Comment: @drum str' object is not callable@DYZ

Comment: Please update your question with the append function

Comment: @drum done.now updated

Comment: no quotes around supplynode

Comment: Then another error 'NameError: name 'supplynode' is not defined'.

Comment: @nicolas could you support me